# Does Kafka delete records or just move the offset?

Tags: apache-kafka

I have read carefully about the possibility of deleting records in Kafka with "kafka-delete-records.sh" and I have also read the following links:

[Confluent Blog](https://www.confluent.es/blog/5-things-every-kafka-developer-should-know/#delete-records)

[KIP 107](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-107%3A+Add+deleteRecordsBefore%28%29+API+in+AdminClient)

[KIP 204](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-204+%3A+Adding+records+deletion+operation+to+the+new+Admin+Client+API)

Despite this, it is not clear to me if what Kafka does is simply move the lowest offset available (via low_watermark) so that consumers can read from there, BUT keeping the "deleted" records in Kafka. Or if, on the contrary, the elimination of records, after having notified all the brokers, ends up being done effectively.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there's topics with `cleanup.policy=delete`, and `retention.ms != -1`, then yes, closed log segments are deleted.

Closing of segments is controlled by `log.segment.bytes` + `log.roll.hours`.

For deleting records in the middle of an open segment, that's where the checkpoint files mentioned in the KIPs are used, and those likely control which low watermarks the brokers report as part of the topic. Once that segment is closed, only then it's subject to retention policies

Comment: Ok, therefore, even though the Kafka documentation indicates that the commit log is immutable, if we can use "kafka-delete-records.sh" to permanently delete the records, we could say that the commit log is NO longer immutable, right?

Comment: I don't think I said it was mutable. A checkpoint file "overrides" what information the client sees and prevents it from seeking to an earlier point in any open segment. Segments being deleted due to retention is not mutation

Comment: So kafka-delete-records.sh deletes the records when indicated by the established retention? or is it independent of the configured retention and removes it roughly when it is executed? I ask this because if it is possible to delete records whenever a user wants, (excluding retention settings), then the commit log is not immutable and I need to know if records can be deleted with kafka-delete-records.sh regardless of the configuration retention.

Comment: @DavidZamora the deleted records are dependent of the cleanup policy (`delete` or/and `compact`) and on the segment rolling configuration (`log.segment.bytes`, `log.roll.hours`). The "deleted" records wont be cleaned before a segment is closed but will be once it is rolled, regardless of the configuration retention.

Comment: @VictorGalisson your comment is the actual answer, thank you. You should post it, as it gets lost here

Answer (score 0):

The deleted records are dependent of the cleanup policy (`delete` or/and `compact`) and on the segment rolling configuration (`log.segment.bytes`, `log.roll.hours`).

The "deleted" records wont be cleaned before a segment is closed but will be once it is rolled, regardless of the configuration retention.

*Posted from my comment to @OneCriketeer as suggested by @Eugene*